# diagnosis on training process of neural network

Tags: optimization, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder, loss-function

I am training an autoencoder DNN for a regression question. Need suggestions on how to improve the training process.

The total number of training sample is about ~100,000. I use Keras to fit the model, setting `validation_split = 0.1`. After training, I drew loss function change and got the following picture. As can be seen here, validation loss is unstable and mean values are very close to training loss.

My question is: based on this, what is the next step I should try to improve the training process?

[**Edit on 1/26/2019**]
The details of network architecture are as follows:
It has 1 latent layer of 50 nodes. The input and output layer have 1000 nodes,respectively. The activation of hidden layer is ReLU. Loss function is MSE. For optimizer, I use Adadelta with default parameter settings. I also tried to set lr=0.5, but got very similar results. Different features of the data have scaled between -10 and 10, with mean of 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By observing the graph provided, the network could not approximate the function which establishes a relation between the input and output.

> If your features are too diverse. That one of them is large and others have a very small value, then you should normalize the feature vector. You can read more [here](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/normalization-of-crazy-data-python-4fa6611e7b46).

For a better training and testing result, you can follow these tips,

1. Use a small network. A network with one hidden layer is enough.
2. Perform activations in the input as well as hidden layers. The output layer must have a linear function. Use ReLU activation function.
3. Prefer small learning rate like 0.001. Use RMSProp optimizer. It works fine on most regression problems.
4. If you are not using mean squared error function, use it.
5. Try slow and steady learning and not fast learning.

Comment: I am actually training an autoencoder. It has 1 latent layer of 50 nodes. The input and output layer have 1000 nodes. The activation of hidden layer is ReLU. For optimizer, I use Adadelta with default parameter settings. I also tried to set lr=0.5, but got very similar results. Different features of the data have scaled between -10 and 10, with mean of 0. Your comments on based on this architecture are very welcome. I add the details of network architecture to the question.

Comment: Try reducing the learning rate to 0.001. And also normalize the features ( ranging from 0 between 1 ).